# WebSocket какой вариант прослушки быстрее?

Tags: сокет, websocket, socket.io

Суть вопроса в том что есть разные библиотеки для получение и отправки данных по WebSocket, так вот, что по вашему мнению или опыту шустрее?

Comment: Сейчас уже давно работает прямо из коробки браузера. Оно то и быстрее, нежели подключать библиотеки.

Comment: Типа прямо из браузера?

Comment: Да [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).